# Is delwin(stdscr) legal?

Tags: c, linux, curses

<s>If it is legal, should I call this always when exiting from ncurses? Or is it automatically called from `endwin()`?</s> What are the consequences of doing `delwin(stdscr)`?

Comment: If it's not legal, there are certainly [a lot of coders](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22delwin%28stdscr%29) that are getting away with it.  I also found [this](http://icculus.org/pipermail/mojosetup/2020-August/000300.html) interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's multiple questions:

> - If it is legal, should I call this always when exiting from ncurses?
> - Or is it automatically called from endwin()?
> - What are the consequences of doing delwin(stdscr)?

The first two are equivalent (it's not necessary in any implementation of curses, and not something that `endwin` does).  Call that two questions, then.  The first asks how **`delwin`** and **`endwin`** are related, and the other asks about specific behavior of **`delwin`**.  The latter is interesting.

Actually it's probably implementation-dependent.

Limiting it to ncurses (per tag),

- [**`delwin`**](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/60696a9f342b0ac39b7e8b47321cfb237b813d5a/ncurses/base/lib_delwin.c#L70) calls
- [**`_nc_freewin`**](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/60696a9f342b0ac39b7e8b47321cfb237b813d5a/ncurses/base/lib_newwin.c#L93), which calls
- [**`remove_window_from_screen`**](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/60696a9f342b0ac39b7e8b47321cfb237b813d5a/ncurses/base/lib_newwin.c#L62), which makes a special check for each of **`curscr`**, **`newscr`** and **`stdscr`** (setting the value of those global variables to NULL if the window to be deleted happens to match, before deallocating their respective data).

So it works for ncurses.  I added the feature in [December 1996](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#t961221):

```
    + modify _nc_freewin() to reset globals curscr/newscr/stdscr when
      freeing the corresponding WINDOW (found using Purify).
```

Regarding portability:

- [PDcurses](https://github.com/wmcbrine/PDCurses/blob/618e0aaa31b4728eb4df78ec4de6c2b873908eda/pdcurses/window.c#L264) does not do this.
- [NetBSD](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/lib/libcurses/delwin.c?rev=1.21&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup) does (but see [this](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/lib/libcurses/delwin.c?rev=1.14&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup) — from 2006, likely imitating [ncurses](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/79ffaf70c141404b5a0df4bafd5aac99d77376bf/ncurses/base/lib_newwin.c#L47))
- Solaris [SVr4 curses](https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/blob/64b8fdd9a26cb9749e154c721f0688932b5e0094/usr/src/lib/libcurses/screen/delwin.c#L51) does not, nor does its X/Open ([xpg4](https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/blob/64b8fdd9a26cb9749e154c721f0688932b5e0094/usr/src/lib/libxcurses2/src/libc/xcurses/newwin.c#L244)) flavor.

There were two questions.  The other regards **`endwin`**.  That never deletes a window, because it is always possible to follow a call to **`endwin`** with a call to **`wrefresh`**.  It's in the [manual page](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-endwin):

```
   Calling refresh(3x) or doupdate(3x) after a temporary escape causes the
   program to resume visual mode.
```

However, if you did a **`delwin(stdscr)`** between the **`endwin()`** and `wrefresh(stdscr)` calls, ncurses would return an error for the latter.  NetBSD ([read the code](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/lib/libcurses/refresh.c?rev=1.112&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup) to see that it will dereference a null pointer) and Solaris would both dump core.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I thought that `endwin()` also frees things related to curses, which was wrong. I wondered why valgrind hates ncurses so much. I have thought that there was some creative memory management involved, but now I know why. :-)

Comment: That's an FAQ: [Testing for Memory Leaks](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#config_leaks)